# How to test Laravel/Lumen API when retrieving the logged in user's ID in controller constructor?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen, laravel-testing

I'm trying to test CRUD operations for my Lumen controllers. The constructor for each controller looks similar to this:

```
  private $loggedInUserId;

  public function __construct(Request $request) {
      $this->loggedInUserId = $request->user()->userId;
  }
```

And here's my test:

```
  public function testShowOneItemReturnsOnePayroll() {
    $this->withoutMiddleware();
    $this->json('GET', "intranet");
    $this->seeJsonStructure([
      'data' => [
        'prId',
        'userId',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        ...
      ]
    ]);
  }
```

I get this error when running the test:

```
PHPUnit\Framework\InvalidArgumentException: Argument #2 of PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertArrayHasKey() must be an array or ArrayAccess
```

**However,** The test is successful when I comment out the `$loggedInUserId` variable and its constructor initialization.

## **Question**

How can I retrieve the user ID in my controllers and still get my tests to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in part thanks to hotsaucejake in [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-test-lumen-api-when-retrieving-the-logged-in-users-id-in-controller-constructor?page=1&replyId=855786) Laracasts post.

I created a `UserFactory` and used it to create a "fake" User model, and referenced it using `actingAs()`:

```
  public function testShowAllItemsReturnsAllPayrollRecords() {
    $user = UserFactory::new()->create();
    $this->withoutMiddleware();
    $this->actingAs($user)->json('GET', 'intranet');
    ...
}
```